# Проблема с занесением математической формулы в код

Tags: c++, математика, nan

Всем привет. Пытаюсь реализовать один из методов решения СЛАУ - *метод ортогонализации*. Были даны формулы по обработке матрицы построчно, вывел формулы для обработки поэлементно, занес в код и... ничего не работает. Программа не крашится, но выводит `nan` вместо необходимых значений.

[Ссылка на формулу для обработки построчно](https://sdo.tusur.ru/pluginfile.php/264058/mod_resource/content/2/%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%20-%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0.pdf) (43ья страница)

Вот мои формулы:
[image: Формула для поэлементного построения матрицы U]
[image: Формула для поэлементного построения матрицы Z]

Уверен, что **проблема кроется где-то в коде**, т.к. при запуске с такими входными данными:

```
1
2
1 2 4
3 4 10
```

Программа не крашится и более того правильно выводит первую строчку матрицы U и одно из значений матрицы Z:

[image: Результат работы программы]

Сам сидел проверял долгое время, но видимо уже просто глаз замылился, не могу найти ошибку. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Прикрепляю код программы (сама реализация формулы начинается в `case 1`):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

long double scalar_product (int vector_order, long double *vector1, long double *vector2)
{
    long double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < vector_order; i++)
        sum += vector1[i] * vector2[i];
    return sum;
}

long double *vector_prod_number (int vector_order, long double *vector1, long double number)
{
    long double *vector2 = new long double [vector_order];
    for (int i = 0; i< vector_order; i++)
        vector2[i] = vector1[i] * number;
    return vector2;
}

long double *vector_minus (int vector_order, long double *vector1, long double *vector2)
{
    long double *vector3 = new long double [vector_order];
    for (int i = 0; i < vector_order; i++)
        vector3[i] = vector1[i] - vector2[i];
    return vector3;
}

long double *vector_plus (int vector_order, long double *vector1, long double *vector2)
{
    long double *vector3 = new long double [vector_order];
    for (int i = 0; i < vector_order; i++)
        vector3[i] = vector1[i] + vector2[i];
    return vector3;
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    ifstream input("input.txt");
    ofstream output("output.txt");
    if (!input.is_open()) return -1;
    int task, matrix_order, i, j, h, k, p, t;
    input >> task >> matrix_order;
    long double  exA[matrix_order + 1][matrix_order + 1], U[matrix_order + 1][matrix_order + 1],
            Z[matrix_order + 1][matrix_order + 1], sumK, sumH, sumT, *test_vector, X[matrix_order];
    for (i = 0; i < matrix_order; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < matrix_order; j++)
            input >> exA[i][j];
        input >> t;
        exA[i][j] = -t;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix_order; i++)
        exA[matrix_order][i] = 0;
    exA[matrix_order][matrix_order] = 1;
    switch (task)
    {
    case 0: //Проверка матрицы и действий с матрицами
        cout << "Расширенная матрица: " << endl;
        for (i = 0; i < matrix_order + 1; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < matrix_order + 1; j++)
                cout << exA[i][j] << " ";
            cout << endl;
        }
        cout << "\nСкалярное произведение первой\nи второй строки расширенной матрицы: " << scalar_product(matrix_order+1,exA[0],exA[1]) << endl;
        cout << "\nУмножение первой строки матрицы\nна число 5: " << endl;
        test_vector = vector_prod_number (matrix_order + 1, exA[0], 5);
        for (i = 0; i< matrix_order + 1; i++)
            cout << test_vector[i] << " ";
        test_vector = NULL;
        cout << "\nПервая строка матрицы минус\nвторая строка:" << endl;
        test_vector = vector_minus (matrix_order + 1, exA[0], exA[1]);
        for (i = 0; i < matrix_order + 1; i++)
            cout << test_vector[i] << " ";
        test_vector = NULL;
        cout << "\nПервая строка матрицы плюс\nвторая строка:" << endl;
        test_vector = vector_plus (matrix_order + 1, exA[0], exA[1]);
        for (i = 0; i < matrix_order + 1; i++)
            cout << test_vector[i] << " ";
        test_vector = NULL;
    break;
    case 1: //Решение СЛАУ
        cout << "Расширенная матрица: " << endl;
        for (i = 0; i < matrix_order + 1; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < matrix_order + 1; j++)
                cout << exA[i][j] << " ";
            cout << endl;
        }
        cout << "\nМатрица U: " << endl;
        for (i = 0; i < matrix_order + 1; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < matrix_order + 1; j++)
            {
                p = 0;
                sumH = 0;
                for (h = 0; h <= i - 1; h++)
                {
                    sumK = 0;
                    for (k = 0; k < matrix_order + 1; k++)
                    {
                        sumK += exA[i][k] * Z[h][k];
                    }
                    sumH += sumK * Z[h][p];
                    p++;
                }
                U[i][j] = exA[i][j] - sumH;
                cout << U[i][j] << " ";
                sumT = 0;
                for (t = 0; t < matrix_order + 1; t++)
                    sumT += U[i][t] * U[i][t];
                Z[i][j] = U[i][j] / sqrt(sumT);
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
        cout << "\nМатрица Z: " << endl;
        for (i = 0; i < matrix_order + 1; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < matrix_order + 1; j++)
                cout << Z[i][j] << " ";
            cout << endl;
        }
        cout << "\nРешение СЛАУ: " << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix_order; i++)
        {
            X[i] = Z[matrix_order + 1][i]/Z[matrix_order + 1][matrix_order + 1];
            cout << "x" << i+1 << " = " << X[i] << endl;
        }
    break;

    case 3:

    break;
    default:
        cout << "Ошибка выбора задания. Попробуйте еще раз";
        return 0;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: при вычислении `Z[i][j]` у тебя `U[i][t]` для `t>=j` оказываются неинициализированными... алгоритм не смотрел — ссылка требует пароля, но, скорей всего, это нужно делать в отдельном цикле...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Премного уважаемый [Fat-Zer](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/277616/fat-zer) объяснил в комменте (почему-то не в ответе), в чем было дело: вся проблема крылась в том, что я при вычислении `Z[i][j]` использовал `U[i][t]`, где `t` со временем выходило за раками инициализированных элементов (короче, я пытался работать с еще не существующими элементами). Кроме того, чуть позже я обратил внимание на то, что при вычислении `X[i]` я пытался работать с последней строкой матрицы `Z` при этом обозначая индексы элементов последней строки так: `matrix_order + 1`, хотя мне стоило обозначать их просто `matrix_order`. После этих исправлений, все заработало.